# How to covert mongodb id to objectId in grails

Tags: mongodb, grails

How to convert any mongo db id like- `50c33766a09e6c5ce3a021a5` to mongo db Object id like- `ObjectId("50c33766a09e6c5ce3a021a5")` in grails?

Answer (score 1):

```
class ObjectIdParser {
    static Serializable parse(String id) {
        return ObjectId.isValid(id) ? new ObjectId(id) : null
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx @Emil This method only convert Id class string to bson.types.ObjectId class .we need this in exact ObjectId("50c33766a09e6c5ce3a021a5") formate...i have need to compare object id's by criteria query in grails

Answer (score 0):

> Thanx @Emil This method only convert Id class string to bson.types.ObjectId class .we need this in exact ObjectId("50c33766a09e6c5ce3a021a5") formate...i have need to compare object id's by criteria query in grails -Raj

Then do compare two strings, but it feels like you are doing something in the wrong way..

```
ObjectId id = new ObjectId("50c33766a09e6c5ce3a021a5")
String otherId = 'ObjectId("50c33766a09e6c5ce3a021a5")'

assert otherId == "ObjectId(/"${id as String}/")"
```